# "Unbox" versatile type of discriminated union / Search for good workaround

Tags: types, f#, type-inference, abstract-syntax-tree, discriminated-union

For a small AST parser i have a small discriminated union

```
type Numerical =
    | Int of int
    | Real of float
```

for the use in some other constructs like

```
type Vector = Numerical list
Vector [Int 42; Real 13.5]
```

When i have a method like this

```
let eval (e:Numerical) =
    match e with
    | Int n -> ... (* return int *)
    | Real r -> ... (* return float *)
```

I know that F# infers the `int` type and produces an error with the `Real` pattern in the second line, so I want to know, which code-design would be the best one to be able to handle such "generic" types and return their appropriate values with the given types.

**EDIT**

I have here an **either or** situation which leads to functions like

```
let getInt = function
| Int n -> n
| Real _ -> failwith "Given value doesn't represent an int"

let getReal = function
| Real n -> n
| Int _ -> failwith "Given value doesn't represent a real number"
```

however i would like a method which encapsulates both cases and "automatically chooses the correct one".

This whole effort should lead to the possibility to be able to really run computations with the "boxed" values like `Int 42` and `Real 13.` with primitive data types but to able to return the appropriate wrapper. If i want to add `Real 1.` and `Real 1.5` I want to extract `1.0 + 1.5 = 2.5` and then go on with `Real 2.5`, however I do not want to handle everything as floats so that I have the distinction between ints and floats.

Comment: What do you want as the return type of `eval`? How do you want to use it?

Comment: @svick: I wrap all my constant expressions like `True, False, Int n, Real r` and want a function that "extracts" their proper values in a representation to execute basic operators like +, - on them. In this case for example `true, false, (int) n, (float) r` if you understand, as I can not write `(Int 42) + (Int 13)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the results to `obj`:

```
let eval (e:Numerical) =
    match e with
    | Int n -> n :> obj
    | Real r -> r :> obj
```

But that's probably not what you want.

Another option would be implement your own operations on `Numerical`:

```
let (+) a b =
    match (a,b) with
    | (Int an, Int bn) -> Int (an + bn)
    | (Real ar, Real br) -> Real (ar + br)
    | _ -> failwith "Can't add Int and Real"
```

You can't have a function that has different compile-time return type based on some run-time value.

Comment: That should do it with tricky pattern matching... F# still seems weird but offers so much cool tricks you can use!

Comment: It may be preferable to define `+` as static member of the `Numerical` type so that it doesn't hide the default global `+` function, i.e. `type Numerical = ... with static member (+)(a,b) = ...`

Comment: @StephenSwensen: Already implemented this after running into some problems ;-) Although thanks for this advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
let eval<'T> (e:Numerical):'T =
    match e with
    | Int n -> n :> obj :?> 'T
    | Real r -> r :> obj :?> 'T
```

**DEMO**

```
> eval<float>(Real 4.5);;
val it : float = 4.5
> eval<int>(Int 42);;
val it : int = 42
> let x:float = eval (Real 5.5);;
val x : float = 5.5
> let x:int = eval (Real 5.5);;//NG typemismatch
```